# two UIImageViews in one UIScrollView! How to zoom in the right UIImageView?

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, ipad, zooming

i have two UIImageViews as childs in one UISCrollView. You can flip sideways to display pages of a brochure. (12 Pages).

Now i wanted to zoom pages. I couldn't get it up till now to zoom the right ImageView.

I know i have to implement

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return someView
}
```

but i don't know how i could return the UIImageView the User is actively zooming in ...

maybe somebody can give me a hint ?

Thanks in advance

MadMaxAPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're solution is 'paging mode'.
See the PageControl example from Apple: [Page Control example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)
I think the example is clear enough.

Success